# Magnetostatics problem involving dipoles

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, magnetostatics

A while back I came across a problem in which I were to find the force of attraction between a magnetic dipole and a spherical iron ball (which is much smaller than the distance between the dipole and the centre of the ball).
The solution was pretty straight forward, I assumed that the field from the dipole magnetizes the sphere, the magnetization sets up a magnetic field, that magnetic field sets up its owm magnetization and so on. Then I summed up the magnetization vectors and got the final magnetic dipole moment. From there it's easy to find the force.

But I've been thinking, what if I replace the sphere with a cylinder or a really thin plate, how would you go about solving this problem?
I tried the same reasoning as for the sphere but I quickly ran into some issues. First of all the initial magnetization doesn't set up a uniform magnetic field within the cylinder and the magnetic dipole density is different for different points of the cylinder. Moreover, even finding the total magnetic moment of the cylinder would not be very helpful since the behavior of the cylinder doesn't necessarily have to be that of an ideal dipole (this, however, could be accounted for by the fact that the cylinder is small compared to the length scale of the problem). Lastly, trying the brute force method of just integrating the force on each volume element is not feasible. I was wondering if there is a better approach to this problem

Comment: In general you have to find the magnetization of a ferromagnet of arbitrary shape numerically, I believe. I am not aware that there is a simple formula that allows us to avoid solving the field equations. There may be pretty good approximations for simple shapes, though.